# C#/WPF/Datagrid How to write a check all items and uncheck all items event

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

In a datagrid I have a checkbox column, with a checkbox header.

I have the two below events binded in xaml so that they fire when the header checkbox is checked or unchecked.

```
    private void check_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Code to check all items
    }

    private void check_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Code to uncheck all items
    }
```

What can I put in these event handlers to check or uncheck all the items (rows) in my datagrid?

Comment: Did you search stackoverflow before you posted?  This question seems to have the answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208004/datagrid-column-header-should-check-uncheck-checkbox-s-state-depending-upon-wh

Comment: The question you linked is asking something more complex.

Comment: What have you tried to put in the handlers?  What does your XAML look like?